# ¿cuando compilo una aplicación para consola en C#, se crean los archivos dll, json y pdb?

Tags: c#, consola, visual, studio, compilador

Hola buen día quisiera que me enseñaran a compilar una aplicación en solo un archivo .exe, ya que no me puedo dar el lujo de tener muchos archivos para un solo programa, dado a que es parte de un entorno, quisiera que solo fuere un .exe que incluya los .dll y los manifiestos y los pdb dentro de sí misma. si no me explique bien por favor hágamelo saber.

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)! Los programas suelen tener varios archivos.. para lo que vos queres, deberias incluir las dll dentro del exe, no sele hacerse... cual seria el problema de tener varios archivos???

Comment: Te invito a leer [ask] y a realizar el [tour]. En [es.so] no somos una academia de enseñanza. Pides que te enseñemos a usar el compilador, pero ¿qué has averiguado o intentado al respecto? ¿Qué ventajas crees que te aporte un ejecutable único con respecto a un paquete instalable? ¿Qué tipo de aplicación para consola estás creando?

Comment: hola amigo, es que la app es para el entorno de windows, y veo que todas las apps del entorno son de un solo archivo y tener 5 archivos para una sola aplicación si me afecta en la organización de los archivos, ya que todos los programas van en el mismo directorio, no puedo tenerlos en carpetas separadas por cuestiones de acceso directo en la terminal, ¿usted sabe cómo generar un solo .exe?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Click derecho en el proyecto y seleccionas "publicar"

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

En la ventana emergente seleccionas algún destino, como por ejemplo "Carpeta" y luego nuevamente "Carpeta" y luego la ubicación de donde se publicará

Luego presionas el icono del lápiz y configuras:

```
Modo de implementación: Independiente
Producir en un único archivo : [check]
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: exelente servicio, me sirvió su solución, de antemano le agradesco su tiempo caballero, muy elaborada su respuesta y precisa.