# Empaquetar todos los recursos y dependencias dentro del Ejecutable (NO Setup)

Tags: visual-studio-2022, .net8

***Contexto:***

Estoy trabajando en un proyecto personal en C#/winform el cual tiene la siguiente estructura:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Cuando estoy desarrollando y quiero probar algo con el modo debug me genera estos archivos (**No Son solo DLLS**):

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

***El problema***

No me agrada como a un 25% de la app luce el directorio debug, veo que hay muchos archivos sueltos, y desde el punto de vista de la arquitectura no creo que sea correcto, concidero que si estoy implementando recursos embebidos y paquetes de nugget, deberian poder estar incrustado dentro del mismo .exe de la aplicación (NO Setup.exe).

***Consulta:***

¿Visual Studio tiene alguna opción en debug o release que me permita empaquetar todo dentro del mismo ejecutable (aplicacion.exe,NO Setup.exe) y evitar la acumulacion de archivos individuales y sueltos?

***Update 1:***

Gracias a [@Yussef](https://es.stackoverflow.com/users/301324/yussef) por tu aporte pero no logro dar con la solucion.

Al intentar hacer los pasos descritos en esta [respuesta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/610657/cuando-compilo-una-aplicaci%C3%B3n-para-consola-en-c-se-crean-los-archivos-dll-js/610658#610658) el primer inconveniente es que los Menu que se despliegan no son iguales o similares... en mi caso especifico uso Visual Studio 2022, has mostrado esta pantalla:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

y en mi Proyecto se despliega esta otra:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

En la respuesta que indicas el resultado es un `.exe` en cambio a mi al lograr ejecutar el proceso de publish, me muestra un setup + Archivos individuales (es lo que quiero evitar):

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

en el camino hice modificaciones para evitar el problema con ClickOnce ... y la ejecucion como administrador.

***Update 1.5***

Dandole seguimiento al aporte de @Yussef logre conseguir ver la misma pantalla/ventana o una similar de `publish` cuando pase todo el proyecto de `.NET4.7` a `.NET8.0` desconosco si esto es algun problema de IDE ya que otros usuarios me reportaron que si veian la nueva vista de `publish`

A pesar de que logre hacer los pasos y de que la mayor parte de las dependencias fueron incrustadadas, el resultado sigue sin ser el esperado, veo archivos pdb y dlls individuales:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

***Update 2***

La Pregunta no es si ustedes opinan si esta bien o mal el empaquetar todo dentro del exe.

La pregunta es: **¿Se puede empaquetar con Visual Studio 2022 todo y que genere un solo .exe?**

No, Si, Como?

Comment: Ver esta respuesta: https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/610657/cuando-compilo-una-aplicaci%c3%b3n-para-consola-en-c-se-crean-los-archivos-dll-js/610658#610658

Comment: Yo uso ILMerge para incrustar dll en mis ejecutables, también puedes usar Costura.Fody

Comment: No nos confundamos: Que toda la aplicación quede como un solo .exe es como muestro en la respuesta. Por otro lado ClickOnce es un instalador que te permite buscar actualizaciones (requiere un servidor web para eso), pero cuando te lo instala descomprime los archivos que pueden ser uno solo (si has hecho lo que te mostré) o pueden ser varios si es que haces la compilación default

Comment: En mi opinión, ves problemas donde no los hay. La mayoría de las aplicación están compuestas por bastantes archivos y van perfectamente. Que la aplicación tarde en arrancar, que no funcione bien, que vaya lenta, esos son problemas, pero que hay varios archivos en principio no es un problema a no ser que tú mismo lo quieras ver como tal

Comment: @FranciscoNuñezIALover. Si un programa va lento es un problema, lo he dicho antes. Tú estás dando opiniones en tu propia pregunta diciendo que es un problema "No me agrada como a un 5% de la app luce el directorio debug, veo que hay muchos archivos sueltos, y desde el punto de vista de la arquitectura no creo que sea correcto". Y estás haciendo juicios de valor acerca de mi intención.

Comment: De tu última actualización toma solo el .exe, cópialo y pégalo en otro lado. Luego ejecútalo y comprueba si funciona correctamente

Comment: Revisa esto https://learn.microsoft.com/es-es/dotnet/core/deploying/single-file/overview?tabs=cli

Comment: @Japv gracias y si he estado toqueteando ese archivo ... por lo que veo la forma mas facil y adecuada es el modo portable con dependencia de framework... seguire testetando... gracias a todos por sus comentarios constructivos.