¿Cuales son las ventajas y desventajas de la publicación con ClickOnce?
estaba haciendo el instalador de mi aplicación de .NET Core 8 en C# y al publicar me dice: Destino (ClickOnce / Carpeta / Azure...), le dí a Carpeta y me sale: Destino específico (ClickOne / Carpeta), ¿qué es ClickOnce, y cuáles son sus ventajas/desventajas? Lo que busco es que me ponga todo en solo un ejecutable, no en .dll, .exe y muchos más, solo un .exe y ya está.

Hace 10 años que no lo uso, así que no se cuánto ha cambiado. Te permite crear un instalador y un servicio de actualización. Te creaba unos archivos, tú lo dejabas alojado en un servidor web y difundías la URL, el usuario descarga e instalaba, y cada que vez que se abre la App esta busca actualizaciones. Tú, como desarrollador, para agregar una nueva versión volvías a usar ClickOnce y republicabas donde mismo en el servidor web.- Por otro lado, para crear un solo .exe puedes ver esta respuesta https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/610658/301324
